# 302 or 307 Redirect?

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, http-status-code-302, http-status-code-307

From a programmatic point of view which is better 302 or 307 for the following? I am going to test two different urls for the same content. One URL is already indexed and I would like it to remain indexed by search engines while the other I would like temporary and not to be indexed since its purpose is to test new programming for a short period of days not weeks. Is there a different approach that should be taken to do this type of testing?

Thank you stackoverflow friends,

Comment: Thanks jsobo I did see that question but it did not quite go into enough detail as it relates to testing two different urls and doing it in an search engine friendly manner.

Comment: 302 and 307 are both for temporary redirects. You need to use 301 for permanent redirects. 302 and 307 are basically the same, as long as you don't use POST request.